# Cypress - exclude tests from beforeEach

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

90% of my tests need to do one task before start so I made beforeEach function that works perfect.

Rest 10% need to do something else before start.

Is in Cypress some way to do beforeEach except some tests?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, but you can do some tricks with it. For example:

```js
describe('describe 1', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
  })
  it('test 1', function(){
  })
  it('test 2', function(){
  })
})

describe('describe 2', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
  })
  it('test 3', function(){
  })
})
```

This way you still have your tests clustered in 1 file, but by separating them to several `describe()`'s you can separate the `beforeEach()`

Comment: Ok, but if I have it (beforeEach) in support folder I can't use it to only some tests?

Comment: can you share some code syntax how you use it at the moment?

Comment: I have made support file which is doing before each test some task. After that it will start again. I figured it out in different way. But thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

As of cypress version 8.2.0 and above, you can use the `Cypress.currentTest` object to check which test is running every time.

```js
describe('describe 1', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        switch(Cypress.currentTest.title) {
             case 'test 3 - i am not so usual':
             // case 'test 4 - not so usual too': (or any other test title)
                  cy.yourCustomCommand()
                  // or let your special test to take control...below
             break;
             default:
                 // do as usual
                 cy.yourStandardCommand()
             break;
        }
    })
    
     it('usual test 1', () => {})
    
     it('usual test 2', () => {})

     it('test 3 - i am not so usual', () => {
          cy.letMeDoMyStaff()
          // ...
     })
})
```

Docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/currenttest